# PHP: Query inside text log files instead of database records

Tags: php, logging

I have a PHP application which generates many logs.
Since I want allow the application administrators to search logs based on parameters such as Used Id or Event Id I store whole logs in MySQL database. It reduces performance of my log table in database and I decided to move my logs to text log files instead of database.
However I have the problem to search through log files or query them and display the result to queries of administrators.

Are there any suggestion to overcome this problem? Are there any practices for this, since this seems a common problem for all application with large number of user.

Are there any practices for managing logs in

Answer (score 0):

You can add your logs to a document-oriented database like ([mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/), [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html), [Redis](https://redis.io/)).
Alternatively, you can use free apps like Prometheus and grafana to view and add alerts ([demo](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/)).